# AppCrash message sent to deallocated instance 0x9d500b0

Tags: animation, label, nstimer, dealloc

I'm trying to keep track of a label with an animation, through NSTimer .
When you start counting the app crashes giving the following error:

```
- [ PFObject objectForKey : ] : message sent to deallocated instance 0x9d500b0
```

What is my problem?
Where am I doing wrong ?

P.S. In my app I'm using Parse.com

I show you the code that creates the problem :

```
-(void)FFQueryForDatiEsami {

    FFTitoloEsameLabel.text = [FFObjectForDetails1 objectForKey:FF_ESAMI_TITOLO];
    NSNumber * CFUNumber = [FFObjectForDetails1  objectForKey:FF_ESAMI_CFU];
    FFCFULabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[CFUNumber intValue]];
    NSDateFormatter *FFDataFormattata = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [FFDataFormattata setDateFormat:FF_DATE_FORMATTER];
    FFDataConvalidaEsameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Convalidato in data %@",[FFDataFormattata stringFromDate:FFObjectForDetails1.updatedAt]];
    FFProgrammazioneEsameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Questo esame era stato programmato per il %@",[FFDataFormattata stringFromDate:[FFObjectForDetails1 objectForKey:FF_ESAMI_DATA_STRING]]];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.020
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(CalcoloVotazione)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

}

-(void) CalcoloVotazione{
    NSTimer *Timer;
    NSNumber * myNumber = [FFObjectForDetails1  objectForKey:FF_ESAMI_VOTAZIONE];

    FFVotazioneLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",TickNumber];
    int number = [myNumber intValue];


    TickNumber++;
    if(TickNumber > number ){
        [Timer invalidate];
        Timer = nil;
    }     
}
```

Comment: You should name your methods and variables starting with a lowercase letter. What do you need the timer for? If you explain better what you're trying to achieve maybe someone can help you.

Comment: Hello moxy, I eventually solved avevbo I wrong .. I had messed with the code: ((((... The biggest problem I am having here now: (

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469533/parse-com-retrieve-boolean-value-in-tableviewcell