# Parse.com : Retrieve Boolean Value in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

Parse.com I'm using in my project .
In my view controller I have a searchbar that fetches data from a class different from the one in which there is a Boolean value that I need.

In a nutshell each cell contains a button that when pushed to disappear because is going to create a Boolean value that as I said above is in another class different from that of the main query .

To help you understand:

The search bar fetches the data from class " _USER " where all reside registered users app

The button instead goes into creating a boolean value in the Class " Friends "

I can not connect the two actions ...

I did some tests but I can not get the result I want .. Can you explain how I might do to fix this? I do not understand where is my mistake

Here I show the query and the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (Void) { retrieveFromParse
   
 
    PFQuery retrievePets * = [ PFQuery queryWithClassName : FF_USER_CLASS ] ;
    [ retrievePets orderByAscending : FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME ] ;
    
    [ retrievePets findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock : ^ ( NSArray * objects , NSError * error ) {
        if ( error) {
            NSLog ( @ "% @ " , objects) ;
            allObjects = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ] ;
            for ( PFObject * object in objects) {
                [ allObjects addObject : object ] ;
                
            }
            
        }
        [ self.FFTableViewFindUser reloadData ] ;
    } ] ;
}






- ( UITableViewCell * ) tableView : ( UITableView * ) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath : ( NSIndexPath * ) indexPath {
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @ " CellFindUser " ;
    
    
    FFCellFindUser * cell = [ self.FFTableViewFindUser dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier : CellIdentifier ] ;
    if ( cell) {
        cell = [ [ FFCellFindUser alloc ] initWithStyle : reuseIdentifier UITableViewCellStyleDefault : CellIdentifier ] ;
    }
    
    
       if (! isFiltered ) {
        
        
        PFObject * object = [ allObjects objectAtIndex : indexPath.row ] ;
        NSString * str = [object objectForKey : FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME ] ;

        cell.FFLabelCell_NomeCognome.text = str ;
        
        
        cell.FFIMGCell_FotoProfilo.image = [ UIImage imageNamed : @ " FFIMG_Camera "] ;
        [ cell.FFIMGCell_FotoProfilo.layer setMasksToBounds : YES] ;
        [ cell.FFIMGCell_FotoProfilo.layer setCornerRadius : 22.5f ] ;
        cell.FFIMGCell_FotoProfilo.file = [object objectForKey : FF_USER_FOTOPROFILO ] ;
        [ cell.FFIMGCell_FotoProfilo loadInBackground ] ;
        
       / / Cell.FFUserButton.tag = indexPath.row ;
       / / [ Cell.FFUserButton addTarget : self action: @ selector ( FFInviaRichiestaAmicizia :)
         / / ForControlEvents : UIControlEventTouchUpInside ] ;
          
           

/ / HERE I AM RECALLING THE BOOLEAN VALUE CLASS FRIENDSHIPS
         
  if ( [ [object objectForKey : @ " RICHIESTA_IN_ATTESA "] boolValue ] ) {
               
               [ cell.FFUserButton setHidden : YES] ;
           Else { }
               [ cell.FFUserButton setHidden : NO] ;
           }

}
```

Comment: So you're listing users and you want to add/remove them from the friend list of the 'current' user?

Comment: Hello Wain, is in practice I would like the add friend button does not appear more 'once clicked ... then the table view must recognize that take a Boolean value that cell and then deletes the button .. Do you think there is a way to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're approaching your problem in the wrong way by using

```
if ( [ [object objectForKey : @ " RICHIESTA_IN_ATTESA "] boolValue ] )
```

because that means that the users need to know if they are the friend of the current user. This is the wrong way round. You current user should have a list of its current friends (either an array of object ids or relationships in Parse). Your table view controller should also have access to the current user. Then, you write the code to show / hide the buttons as:

Note: `currentUserFriends` is an array of user object ids built from the relationship / information on the current user

```
[cell.FFUserButton setHidden:([currentUserFriends containsObject: object.objectId])];
```